# How to get current tag inside controller? - Flutter GetX

Tags: flutter, dart, get, state, flutter-getx

I created a controller with tag, i need to access that tag inside controller, is it possible?

This is how i put controller

```
final ProfileController _profileController = Get.put(ProfileController(), tag: "12345etc");
```

i will use that tag inside **ProfileController** but i can not access that tag.

```
class ProfileController extends GetxController {
    //load info from 12345etc userid
    Future<void> viewProfile() {
        Services.loadProfileInfo("12345etc")...
    }
}
```

tag **12345etc** will load from another controller it wont be a fixed text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use field to keep the tag inside the controller

```
class ProfileController extends GetxController {
    final String tag;

    ProfileController (this.tag);

    Future<void> viewProfile() {
        // And use it like this
        Services.loadProfileInfo(tag);
    }
}
```

And pass the tag during instantiation

```
Get.put(ProfileController("12345etc"), tag: "12345etc");
```